# Understanding file pointers and buffers

Tags: c

Why, in C, do you need a separate buffer to read a `FILE *`?  When you declare a `FILE *` and assign to it with `fopen`, does the file then not exist in contiguous memory starting at the address of said pointer? I'm struggling to make the connection as to why you need need to read via `fread()` into a separate buffer. If someone could explain how the`FIlE *file = fopen(filename, "r")` and the subsequent `fread(&buffer,...)` work in conjunction it would help my understanding tremendously.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my answer below , it might help you understand the reason 'why'?

Comment: No, the file does not exist in memory unless it's really small. `FILE*` is a structure that holds, among other things, a file descriptor that allows the program to read the file from the disk through syscalls. You can also read a file using syscalls directly, using `open()`, `read()` and `write()`, but by using syscalls directly you won't be making efficient use of read/write buffering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation given above is pretty much self explanatory , still I would try to make it simple (in case anyone has problem understanding it)

**In Short,consider this example and you yourself would know 'why?'**

*1) your files might be too large and stored in your hard drive , then if you try reading it frequently, don't you think this is an overhead for loading whole file again and again.*

*2) And more worse say the file is huge then if you load whole of your file it consumes your RAM even if you don't need whole file at once.*

> Why, in C, do you need a separate buffer to read a FILE *?

First thing, Because reading into buffers and then using it is always faster.

> does the file then not exist in contiguous memory starting at the
>   address of said pointer?

May or May not be ,depending on its size.

> If someone could explain how theFIlE *file = fopen(filename, "r") and
>   the subsequent fread(&buffer,...) work in conjunction

The fopen() function is used to open a file and associates an I/O stream with it. This function takes two arguments. The first argument is a pointer to a string containing name of the file to be opened while the second argument is the mode in which the file is to be opened.

Various modes can be like `r, r+, w, w+, a, a+` .

The fopen() function returns a FILE stream pointer on success while it returns NULL in case of a failure.

Look [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/c-file-handling) for detailed info.

Answer (score 3):

The `FILE *` returned by `fopen` is an unnecessary, but useful, layer of indirection.

Theoretically, `fopen` could have been designed to read the whole file into a buffer in memory, and just return you that buffer.

The issue approach is that it's not flexible at all. It forces you to read the entire file for all file IO operations, which is *very* undesirable. For example, here are some problems that would come about:

- How could you read a file that's too big to fit in RAM?
- What if you just want to append a new line at the end of a file (such as for logging). You would have to read the whole file, append the line at the end, then rewrite the entire file back. Expensive!
- What if you're only interested in reading a small part of a file, such as reading the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) to identify the file's type, without regard for its actual content?
- What if you wanted to simultaneously edit the file from multiple programs. Each program need to constantly reread the whole file into memory, to ensure it kept up-to-date.

`fopen` returns a file handle that identifies a file still on disk. How much you read out of this file into memory is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

> Why, in C, do you need a separate buffer to read a FILE *?

No buffer aren't necessary while they are usually present to accelerate I/Os.

> When you declare a FILE * and assign to it with fopen, does the file
>   then not exist in contiguous memory starting at the address of said
>   pointer?

Certainly not, 'cause this would be at least inefficient (why read a entire file huge if it is not needed at the end?) and at worst impossible at all (RAM size is usually much less than DISK size).

> If someone could explain how the FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r") and
>   the subsequent fread(&buffer,...) work in conjunction it would help my
>   understanding tremendously.

Then FILE * is not an handle to a memory object that contains the file data, but is a memory object that contains data to help accessing file data on disk. That opaque object (opaque means don't try to look inside details are hidden) contains for example the current offset (remember when you read or write this is done at a given offset and this would modify the offset accordingly), or the open mode (this way writing into an opened for read file will correctly fails), or some buffer (that may contains part of the file and sometimes the whole file!), etc. A FILE * is handle as a handle for a door. Don't confuse file and FILE*, the first is a generic term to embrace what you already know (data on disk), then second is a type to represent an **opened file** which is a dynamic object to represent manipulation of a given file.

> I'm struggling to make the connection as to why you need need to read
>   via fread() into a separate buffer.

If you don't have/can't have the file in memory, then you need to ask for reading the part you are interested in.